# Stripe subscription not returning payment_intent to charge customer

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am using below code to make sunscription. after subscription i am not getting any payment_intent
to charge money . How can i charge customer

```
    # https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object?lang=python
    def create_stripe_subscription(customer_id, price_id):
        stripe.api_key = STRIPE_API_KEY

        res = stripe.Subscription.create(
            customer=customer_id,
            items=[
                {"price": price_id},
            ],
            payment_behavior='default_incomplete',
            expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
        )
        return res
```

You can fine the stripe subscription response here.

```
https://codeshare.io/AdvXNx
```

Please take a look

Answer (score 3):

When creating a subscription with a free trial or with an amount lower than the [minimum that can be charged on Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts) (0.50 for USD), the subscription won't have a `latest_invoice.payment_intent` since there's nothing that can be charged.

When that happens, the subscription will contain a [`pending_setup_intent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-pending_setup_intent) to collect payment information if needed.